# Getting multiple elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There is a drop down menu in the web application when the users select any one of the option from the drop down menu, I have to generate a text box and check box. I have implemented `onSelect` on drop down menu and I have called a function which actually calls the function which adds the text but I need to generate the check box along with the textbox.

I tried to call one more function but that's not working I also tried to using `&&` even that is not working and I have tried to call a function inside the function even that is not working. How do I do this?

This is the code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(type) {
 
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    
    
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("value", type);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);
    
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
 
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    //var element=document.createElement("checkbox");
    //var foo=document.getElementById("foobar");
    //foo.appendChild(element);
    var a=1;

    if(a==1){
        function add2(type) {
 
            //Create an input type dynamically.
        var chkbox = document.createElement("checkbox");
            //Assign different attributes to the element.
            
        chkbox.setAttribute("type", type);
            chkbox.setAttribute("value", type);
            chkbox.setAttribute("name", type);
    
            //var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
        //Append the element in page (in span).
            appendChild(chkbox);
        }
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Show us the code that isn't working, then we get tell you why it isn't wrong and suggest improvements.

Comment: I think you're looking for `document.createElement`, but can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with that you have and provide the link so we can see where's you're at this far? (or at the very least provide some code)

Comment: Unless you post your code, we can't help you.

Comment: This question lacks description!

Comment: @Harish [This question lacks discipline!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qtw4NVMDCYg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way to do it will be call a function with arguments on select from drop down menu but you have to generate arguments for each link in drop down menu

```
function fuc1( arg1 , arg2, ... )
{
            //you can use these agruments to genetate attrs of input and other things
    var input = $("<input></input>").attr({'type': 'text', 'id': someid, 'class': 'someclass' , ... }).val(someval);
    var chbox = $("<input></input>").attr({'type': 'checkbox', 'id': someid, 'class': 'someclass' , ... });

    $(input).appendTo(something);
    $(chbox).appendTo(something);
}
```

it generally works this way. if you submit your code then it might a bit help you

updates::

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function fuc1()
{
        //you can use these agruments to genetate attrs of input and other things
    var container = $("<div></div>").appendTo($('#content'));
    var input = $("<input></input>").attr({'type': 'text'});
    var chbox = $("<input></input>").attr({'type': 'checkbox'});

    $(input).appendTo(container);
    $(chbox).appendTo(container);
}

</script>

<div id="content"></div>
<a href="javascript: fuc1()">add</a>
```

Comment: so you have same code then it must work. if it does not work (with slight modifications) then plz update you question where it did not work (and with the code please)

Comment: @Jeevan i highly recommend you to use jquery or other javascript library beacause it highly simplifies javascript. my jquery version  code has been updated. please if you need in javascript then i will do it  by the after tomorrow